# dynamically update the price

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I need help with a JavaScript function that I don't know how to implement.
I need to make a store for a school project, and I need the price to dynamically update when adding / removing quantities.
Here is a picture of the store, the +/- button work correctly and all I just need to update the price in the add button.
I tried writing a function that will take the price below the name of the product and multiply it by the value in the quantity box but it's not working.

```
<button class="buttonshad buttonstyling bg-primary text-light mx-5">Add <a id="changingprice">$6.99</a></button>
```

[image: picture]

Here is my JavaScript function for increasing and decreasing:

```
  function increaseValue() {
    value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  }

  function decreaseValue() {
    value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  }
```

Basically what I need is to update the price in the button when I add / remove quantity!

Comment: Please sahre a meaningful amount of code, also the image link is missing.

Comment: Post your JavaScript function in the question for better understanding

Comment: An anchor (`<a>`) inside a `<button>`? Weird.

Comment: I edited my post with your recommendation:)

Comment: Not just weird, also invalid!

Comment: whoops that's my bad ! I meant to put it in site a span not an anchor, so I could modify it without modifying the button, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for your inspiration.

```js
let basePrice = 6.99;
document.querySelector("#qty").addEventListener("change", function(){
  document.querySelector("#changingprice span").innerText = (basePrice * this.value).toFixed(2)
})
```

```css
#qty{
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="qty" min="0" value="0"/>
<button id="changingprice" class="buttonshad buttonstyling bg-primary text-light mx-5">Add $<span>0.00</span></button>
```

Comment: Ill try this right now ! Ill get back to you soon, thanks !!!